# Copy Updated AVG definitions to another computer

Tags: anti-virus, updates, avg-antivirus

#### Situation:

I've installed **AVG Anti-virus Free** on two computers and I'm using **Windows 7** on both. One of PCs is connected to internet and I use AVG online-update to update it time to time, but the second does not have any access to internet/network.

One way for updating the second one is the offline option: downloading new definitions from **[AVG website](http://free.avg.com/gb-en/download-update)** as a EXE pack and installing it using a USB flash disk drive. But the size of offline virus-definitions is really large and contains all of the virus definitions while I just need the *updated* and *new* definitions.

A good idea is using the definitions on first computer to update the second computer. But how?

---

#### Not a good solution:

Some guys on internet suggested that AVG saves new definitions in this path:

```
X:\ProgramData\avg9\update\download
```

then I would copy this folder to second computer and use **Update from directory** option in **AVG**.

The problem is the definitions in this folder is deleted whenever somebody request from AVG to *delete temporary update files*. Therefore, if somebody (maybe myself!) accidentally delete the definitions without copying them to second computer, the second computer misses the updates forever!

---

#### The Question:

However, it is clear that after deleting temporary updates, AVG is still updated on first computer, so it must keep new definitions somewhere else.

I want to know where and how I can use them to update the second computer.

Comment: What about simply using update packages? http://free.avg.com/ww-en/download-update

Comment: @Shiki: update packages are nice but they are really big packages! I cannot download them everytime I need an update. I just want the new definitions not the whole package.

Comment: Well.. thats a different story. I'd grab the whole damn package. Bandwidth is much cheaper I guess than anything else. ^^"

Comment: @Shiki, it's cheap except in the third world countries :(

Comment: True. What about using 7zip beta + LZMA2 to compress? Other things can be like copying it with task scheduler and scheduling the update on the other pc after it. OR copy all those updates on your PC to dropbox, and install dropbox on others + copy them + use the copy as update source?

Comment: i can't compress a file on AVG server before downloading it!
the most efficient way is for updating is online update which only download new virus definitions. 
But how i can update another computer with definitions on this updated computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using "Sync Center"? If I am right, you should be able to share your -
C:\ProgramData\avg10\update folder with your second computer. I have yet to test this
option, but it looks like it should do the trick for you.

Comment: I switched to `Microsoft Security Essentials` and do not have AVG to try this. Anyway, this seems to be the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

Download the latest AV files here

Paid versions

http://www.avg.com/us-en/download-update

AVG Free

http://free.avg.com/us-en/download-update

.

Comment: Please read the question. I don't want to download the updates for each PC. I want a "one-time download and copy to other computers" solution

Comment: Maybe you should re-write the question to be more clear.